# Does apache beam bigquery IO connector supports operations on external tables

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Beam has bigquery IO support to be able to read and write to bq tables. I am assuming it only supports bigquery internal tables however if anyone knows if it supports writing to and reading from bq external tables? I think read should be possible but haven't tried myself.